# python call function on whole class

Tags: python, methods

I'm playing around for the first time with pygame, I'd like to know if there is a way I can call a function on a whole class like so:

```
class Char():
def __init__(self,typ,sid):
    self.type=typ
    self.x=0
    self.y=0
    self.vx=0
    self.vy=0
    self.frame=0
    self.sid=sid
    self.bord = sheets[sid].get_rect()
    self.rct = pygame.Rect((0,0),(self.bord.bottom,self.bord.bottom))

player = Char("player",0)
test = Char("test",1)

myfunct(#All Chars())
```

This is how I plan on implementing a few simple physics that I'd like to all apply to each Char(), full code [here](http://www.filedropper.com/tdp).

Comment: There's nothing that automatically makes a list of all instances of a class. If you want to keep a list of all `Char`s, do that in your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add them all to a list which is a class variable, like so:

```
class Char():
    all = []
    def __init__(self,typ,sid):
        self.type=typ
        self.x=0
        self.y=0
        self.vx=0
        self.vy=0
        self.frame=0
        self.sid=sid
        self.bord = sheets[sid].get_rect()
        self.rct = pygame.Rect((0,0),(self.bord.bottom,self.bord.bottom))

        self.all.append(self)

player = Char("player",0)
test = Char("test",1)

myfunct(Char.all)
```

And if you want to apply your function to each object individually, you can just use a `map(myfunct, Char.all)`, but you probably knew that.

Comment: hah no i didnt i'm kinda new to programming, actually i just read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_variable) but i really still dont get what a class variable is, could you develop a little bit on how i can access it, is it a list, or an "original" instance that is linked to all others(like a js.prototype)

Comment: @poolmatho Class variables are defined in the main body of the class, and are accessed using dot notation with the class name i.e. `ClassName.class_variable`. Inside the actual function, they can be referred to with `self.class_variable`. Make sure you don't make any instance variables called the same thing as a class variable though :)

Comment: ok great that helped and the code seems to run just fine, thank you very much